# How to auto run routes - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I  created my web-hooks for my apps which work fine. But i have noticed that, before my web-hooks will work, i have to register them by running the route in the browser before they are registered.

So if my route is `https://example.domain/order-create-webhook`, i have to run this route, to call the function `registerOrderCreateWebhook()` to register my web-hook in the application before ,i can start receiving response from Shopify.

Now my question, is there a way that i can auto run this route as user is installing the application so i wouldn't have to manually register my web-hooks from the browser

**NB: I have added my auth() that is registers/ installs a new user for the application**

**Controller**

```
public function auth(Request $request)
{



 $shared_secret = env('SHARED_SECRET');
    $params = $_GET; 
    $shop_name = $request->shop;
    $shopUrl = $request->domain;
    $hmac = $request->hmac;
    $code = $request->code;
    $params = array_diff_key($params, array('hmac' => ''));
    ksort($params); 


    $computed_hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', http_build_query($params), $shared_secret);


        $api_key = "*****";
        $shared_secret = "****";
        $query = array(
        "client_id" => $api_key, // Your API key
        "client_secret" => $shared_secret, // Your app credentials (secret key)
        "code" => $request->code // Grab the access key from the URL
        );

        $shopUrl = $shop_name;
        $access_token_url = "https://" . $shopUrl . "/admin/oauth/access_token";


        // Store the access token
        $result = json_decode($result, true);
        $access_token = $result['access_token'];
        // dd($access_token);



    // Valicate Shopify's request
    if (hash_equals($hmac, $computed_hmac)) {
        if (! User::where('site', '=', $shop_name)->exists()) {

            // Create a new user account                 
            $new_user = new User;
            $new_user->site = $shop_name;
            $new_user->access_token = $access_token;
            $new_user->save();
        }

        // Get current user, login and redirect to dashboard
        $user = User::where('site', '=', $shop_name)->firstOrFail();
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect('/home');

    } 
    else 
    {
        abort(401, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }
}

  public function registerOrderCreateWebhook()
            {
                    $shop = Auth::user()->site;
                    $token = Auth::user()->access_token;
                    $shopify = Shopify::setShopUrl($shop)->setAccessToken($token);
                    Shopify::setShopUrl($shop)->setAccessToken($token)->post("admin/webhooks.json", ['webhook' => 
                     ['topic' => 'orders/updated',
                     'address' => 'https://example.domain.com/order-update-webhook',
                     'format' => 'json'
                     ]
                    ]);
            }
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('order-create-webhook', Controller@registerOrderCreateWebhook);
```

Comment: `artisan route:cache`

Comment: @miken32 can you explain how it works ?

Comment: You run it, and it builds the route cache, rather than waiting for a request to add a route to the cache. I believe that it does what you're looking for.

Comment: @miken32, i will have to try it and see how it works. I want to make sure that whenever any user installs the app, the route `https://example.domain/order-create-webhook` must auto run to install the webhooks for the new user

Comment: Which package are you using and what setup steps have you followed?

Comment: @TravisBritz I am using Osei-Ntow package for Shopify. I have followed every step but now, i want my web-hooks to register as user installs the app

Comment: What prevents you from executing `registerOrderCreateWebhook()` from within `auth()` ?

Answer (score 0):

When merchant hit install button in the Shopify and redirected back to your app you should first fetch AccessToken , store it in the localDB and then you should create webhooks. I am using the same package pasting my code how am I managing all this stuff.

[Basic Shopify App built with laravel](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bhargavkaklotara/shopify-basic-app/master/app/Http/Controllers/ShopifyController.php)

Where autheticate function is called after merchant hit install button in the Shopify.